# How can I read the fully rendered html of a web page using vb.net?

Tags: html, vb.net, google-chrome

I'm assuming my request here isn't possible, but I'll ask anyway, just in case!

I am interested in trying to read the complete html of a sportsbook web site page displayed in a chrome browser, so that I can access the details and odds of each competitor in an event.

The thing is, most of the content is created dynamically. So if I right click and select "View page source" this only gives me the core html and none of the "detail". However, if I right click and select "Inspect" then I can access all the details I want, because this is the fully rendered version of the page.

So, using vb.net, is there any way that I can access the fully rendered page? This will obviously need to be done frequently and I need to interact with the page itself so I can't just use the basic inspect tool within chrome.

I do have a work around - taking screen shots and pixel scraping - but if I can inspect all of the page's elements, that will definitely be better especially as I will be able to read competitors whose display is off the bottom of the screen.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can ask the Server to send you that page using a qualified tool, as the WebBrowser class (`class`, not `Control`, AKA Head-less-Browser), or WebView2 (not yet exactly straightforward), or [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/). The latter can load and render the HTML from the Web directly (see the example in the introduction page).

Comment: Have you tried right-click and 'Save As...' ('Web Page, Complete')? That may give you a static view of the complete page. Dynamically, you may have better luck using the JavaScript console, where you should be able to inspect/interact with everything... and you can save 'bookmarklets' to take those actions at the click of a button, or potentially use 'Local Overrides'...